# Compiler error and Money class assignment

Tags: java, methods, parameters, constructor, compiler-errors

I keep getting the Error "constructor Money in class Money cannot be applied to given types; required: no arguments; found int, int; reason:actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Also here is my list of objectives for the program which I'll be graded on, If you notice any other errors in my code which I may run into later please feel free to point them out for me!

Use BlueJ to create a Money class with two integer instance variables, dollars and cents.
Provide the following methods:

1. A two-parameter constructor that initializes the instance variables. The constructor
   should check that the cents value is between 0 and 99, and if not, transfer some of
   the cents to the dollars variable to make it between 0 and 99.
2. A default constructor that initializes the dollars to 0 and cents to 1. It should call
   the two-parameter constructor.
3. A one parameter constructor that initializes the cents value while setting the
   dollars value to 0. This constructor should also check that the cents value is
   between 0 and 99, and if not, transfer some of the cents to the dollars variable to
   make it between 0 and 99.
4. Accessors for dollars and cents
5. The standard toString method
6. The standard equals method that compares if two Money objects have the same
   state.
7. The plus method that takes a Money object as its parameter. It creates and returns a
   new Money object representing the sum of the object whose plus() method is
   being called and the parameter. It does NOT modify the values of the two existing
   objects.

Finally, create a MoneyDemo class that creates multiple Money objects. This demo class
should test all constructors and methods that you have implemented.

Here is my code:

```
public class Money
 {
     private int dollars, cents;
     private static final int CENTS_PER_DOLLAR = 100;

     public void checkMoney(int dollars, int cents)
     {
         while (cents<0) 
         {
             cents += 100;
             dollars--;
         }
         while (cents>99) 
         {
             cents -= 100;
             dollars++;
         }
     }

     public Money()
     {
         this.cents = 1;
         this.dollars = 0;
     }

     public void initializeCents(int cents)
     {
         while (cents<0) 
         {
             cents += 100;
             dollars--;
         }
         while (cents>99) 
         {
             cents -= 100;
             dollars++;
         }
     }

     public int getDollars()
     {
         return dollars;
     }

     public int getCents()
     {
         return cents;
     }

     public String toString()
     {
         String str;
         dollars = dollars + cents / CENTS_PER_DOLLAR;
         cents = cents % CENTS_PER_DOLLAR;
         str = "Your total amount is: " + "$" + dollars + "." + cents +"";
         return str;
     }

     public Money plus(Money y) 
     {
         return new Money(y.dollars, y.cents);
     }
 }

public class MoneyDemo 
 {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {

         int dollars = 5;
         int cents = 80;
         Money x = new Money( dollars, cents);
         x.checkMoney();

         dollars = 7;
         cents = 70;
         Money y = new Money( dollars, cents);
         y.checkMoney();

         USMoney z = x.plus(y);

         System.out.println( "x: $" + x.dollars + "." + x.cents + "c");
         System.out.println( "y: $" + y.dollars + "." + y.cents + "c");
         System.out.println( "x.plus(y): $" + z.dollars + "." + z.cents + "c");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling

`Money x = new Money( dollars, cents);` with two arguments

And you have define it as

```
public Money()  // no argument constructor
{
     this.cents = 1;
     this.dollars = 0;
}
```

So make it like this:

```
public Money() // no argument constructor
{
     this.cents = 1;
     this.dollars = 0;
}
public Money(int dollars,int cents) // parametrized constructor
{
     this.cents = dollars;
     this.dollars = cents;
}
```

So that it can work for both a parameter-less constructor and a parametrized constructor with two arguments

UPDATE: for `plus`method`

```
public Money plus(Money y) 
{
    Money m = new Money();
    int totalCents = y.cents + this.cents;
    int totalDollars = y.dollars + this.dollars;
    if(totalCents > 100)
    {
       totalDollars = totalDollars + (int)(totalCents / 100);
       totalCents = (int)(totalCents % 100);
    }

    m.dollars = totalDollars;
    m.cents = totalCents;

    return m;
}
```

Comment: I suggest changing the body of the no-arg constructor to `this(0, 1);`. That way, any other constructor work would only need to be added to one constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added the line and after doing a bit of reading this makes sense now. However I am now getting the same error in my MoneyDemo class at the line x.checkMoney();
am I not calling the checkMoney method correctly? I'm confused as I already have the dollars and cents defined...

Comment: you have similar problem there you define it as `public void checkMoney(int dollars, int cents)` and you are calling it as `m.checkMoney()` without any arguments

Comment: 0 down vote accept
 

After asking around a bit I decided to try and clean up my code. I believe I solved my problems with my constructor and toString methods, however I am still having trouble understanding the equals and plus method. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my new code:

Answer (score 0):

The error that you get means that you do not have a constructor that takes the parameters you're trying to pass (two ints). The only constructor you have takes no parameters:

```
public Money()
```

You need to create a new constructor that reads

```
public Money (int cents, int dollars) 

    //make sure that cents is between 0 and 99, if not transfer some cents to dollars
```

You will need a third constructor to satisfy # 3 on your assignment:

```
public Money (int cents) 
    initialize cents based on the parameter passed into it
    set dollars = 0
```

You also need to override the equals() method.

As this is a homework assignment, I'm not going to tell you how to do each of these things.

Let me know if I can talk you through anything, though, or explain anything in more detail.